# AWS MediaConvert: Delete original file after transcoding

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I'm using AWS Media Convert to convert my videos to other formats. I want to be able to delete the original media files as soon as the transcoding is done..How is this possible?? 
I'm using Boto3 SDK

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Set the source and destination path the same

Comment: This is sad, I am sending the converted file to a different bucket. :/